# removing duplicates from NSMutableArray with NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsset

I am trying to set up a NSSet to remove all duplicates from a NSMutableArray of NSDictionary Objects, However I am not sure on how to set one of the values needed for creating the NSSet to an element in the NSDictionary Objects of the NSMutableArray... hopefully that makes sense.

This is what the NSDictionary looks like

```
ID = 22;
SERIESID = 33;
YEAREND = 2002;
YEARSTART = 1996;
```

This is my code so far

```
NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:yearArray];

// iterate over the unique items
for(id element in uniqueElements) {
    // create new NSArray of unique entries
}
```

I would like to know how to create a unique yearArray based off the SERIESID value of each NSDictionary in the yearArray.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Is yearArray the mutable array from which you are trying to remove duplicates?

Comment: Updated my question with **I would like to know how to create a unique yearArray based off the SERIESID value of each NSDictionary in the yearArray.** I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Not really. Do you want to end up with an array of SERIESID's and nothing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
NSMutableArray *resultantArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSDictionary *dict in yearArray)
{
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SERIESID == %@",
                                          [dict valueForKey:@"SERIESID"]];

  NSArray filteredArray = [resultantArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

  if(![filteredArray count])
  {
    [resultantArray addObject:dict];
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the solution given by Suhas :

```
NSMutableArray *resultantArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray * yearArrayCopy = [yearArray copy];
for(NSDictionary *dict in yearArrayCopy)
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SERIESID == %@",
                                      [dict valueForKey:@"SERIESID"]];

    NSArray *filteredArray = [yearArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if([filteredArray count])
    {
        [resultantArray addObject:dict];
        [yearArray removeObjectsInArray:filteredArray];
    }  
}
```

The "resultantArray" will contain only unique elements.